# How to distinguish between uses of words like 'Marry'?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, verbs, transitivity

Marry can be used both transitively:

> "Paul Married Jane"

and intransitively:

> "I got married".

Thus making the word *ambitransitive*

But it has a third use:

> "Paul, the vicar Married Jane to Bob"

The last use is certainly transitive, but what is the word for this use?

Is this to do with (un)accusative and (un)ergative verbs?

Comment: I don't recognise the term *ambitransitive*, but my understanding of a *ditranstive/bitransitive* verb is that it can take two objects *without either of them needing to be introduced by a preposition*. So the vicar can "ditransitively" *give **them advice***, but it would only be a "[mono-]transitive" usage if he *gave **advice** to **them***.

Comment: You can use context.

Comment: As is normal in English (and presumably to a greater or lesser extent, *all* languages), the precise meaning of any utterance depends on context (both the surrounding words, and the circumstances within which the utterance was made). Your "third use" strikes me as extremely unusual - apart from anything else, I would infer that the speaker was far closer to Jane than to Bob, since the *"to Bob"* bit sounds almost like a tacked-on afterthought (he might just as well have married her to Tom, Dick or Harry, but it just so happens it was Bob).

Comment: In the phrase 'I got married', *to marry* is still transitive.  It is simply in the passive voice, which may obscure the exact relationship between subject and object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Words like *Marry*" are called **Reciprocal** Verbs, or Predicates, or Constructions.

They refer to sets (normally couples) of agents, instead of to a single agent. *Marry* is prototypic.
Reciprocal predicates have unusual syntactic affordances, like the ability to swap subject and object without altering meaning. 
Note:

- *Bill and Sue married yesterday* (dual subject, intransitive)
- *Bill married Sue yesterday ~ Sue married Bill yesterday* (subj~obj swap, transitive)

These meanings of *marry* are **Inchoative** -- they refer to change of state. Bill and Sue entered the state of *being married*, a **Stative** meaning. The adjective *married* describes the state, not the event of its inception:

- *Bill and Sue are married* (predicate adjective, not a passive)
- *Bill is married to Sue ~ Sue is married to Bill*
- *Bill is married ~ Bill is a married man*
- *Sue is married ~ Sue is a married woman*
- *George is not married ~ George is an unmarried man*

but note

- *George is not married to Sue* vs **George is unmarried to Sue*

Finally, as usual when there is a Stative and an Inchoative sense of a verb (whether reciprocal or not), there is also a **Causative** sense of *marry*, meaning 'Cause to marry', and running through all the changes of the other senses, viz

- *George married Bill and Sue.*
- *George married Bill to Sue. ~ George married Sue to Bill.*
- *Sue's father married her off young (to Bill).*
- *The couple's parents married them off young.*

To summarize, *marry* has

1. a **stative** sense as a predicate adjective *be married*
   (derived from a past participle, but without verbal powers)
2. an **inchoative** sense meaning 'come to be/become married'
   (a reciprocal verb, allowing argument-swapping)
3. a **causative** sense meaning 'cause to become married'
   (in several senses of *cause*, and several senses of *marry*)

Each one has different uses, constructions, and stigmata.

Comment: Yup, that's a common pattern: Stative ~ Inchoative ~ Causative. Often the same verb, often something different. _Dead - Die - Kill;  Seated ~ Sit ~ Set; Closed ~ Close ~ Close; Open ~ Open ~ Open_. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

When it is used passively (I got married), there seems to be no problem.

But in other cases, context is everything.

I might very well say

> My friend Bob married me.

That might either mean I married Bob, or it might imply he performed the ceremony leading to me being married to my wife (who may, or may not be named Bob).

The moment three people are mentioned, it is usually not that hard to distinguish object, indirect object and subject, in which case the objects are the ones that end up as a couple by the action of the subject.

Comment: Wouldn't Bob in OP's example be an indirect object? (probably treated as dative in Latin)

Comment: Hi, I've clarified my question.

Comment: @d'alar'cop yes, indeed, I think so :) (sorry for any confusion my use of Bob may have caused as to Bob's marital status :P )

Comment: There is also the simple fact that because most people will use the sense that meant Bob is now your wife or husband, we'll assume that unless we have a good reason to suspect otherwise (if they were called "Fr. Bob" perhaps, or you had said "My friend Bob, the marriage registrar"), in which case because those two cases give us a context in which performing marriages is more common than getting married, we'll then assume *that* until yet more information makes it clear we should do otherwise.

Comment: @JonHanna: that is entirely true, but the default interpretations are shifting. In the Netherlands, people can perform weddings under a temporary license, so it might be a one-off special favor to a friend. And of course, the fact _that_ one might assume Bob became my husband (me being a man) already shows how shifting social habits complicate our language interpretation. 20 years ago "Bob married me" would have clearly indicated that Bob performed the ceremony, if the sentence was spoken by a man :) They never seem to think of linguistic complications when discussing equal rights :(

Comment: If you re-read my comment you'll see I didn't assume either way about whether Bob was your wife or husband, "Bob" being a name sometimes used for Roberta :) It doesn't that much change that we'll parse based on the information presented. I have both married, and also married, and find that in practice unless I were to deliberately phrase things ambiguously like just there, it's easy to phrase toward the assumptions made being the correct ones.

Comment: Poor Bob. By now we are unsure about their gender, as well as marital status. And that on Valentine's. What will become of Bob tonight...