# Grammar query - is vs. are

Tags: grammar

The sentence in concern is :
We agreed that Coco and Rocky **are** not the same dog. 
Shouldn't it be: We agreed that Coco and Rocky **is** not the same dog. ? According to my Word grammar editor, **is** is the correct form of the verb there. It doesn't sound right, though.

Comment: Your Word grammar editor is completely confused. Even if Coco and Rocky *were* the same dog, you would say *"Coco and Rocky are the same dog"*. (Even though there is only one singular dog.)

Comment: Do not look to Microsoft as an authority on... anything.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Go to rise4fun.com - they've been busy lately it would seem.

Comment: Haha alright @ErnestFriedman-Hill.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you. I needed this clarified haha.

Comment: Yes. It depends on the construction, not a simple view of the situation being put into words. **Batman and Bruce Wayne are the same man** , the hero who famously keeps crime off the streets of Gotham City. Compound subject treated as separate notions even though they have the same referent: plural agreement. **Batman (Bruce Wayne) is the man** who keeps crime off the streets of Gotham City._Appositive, 'renaming' of one referent, not seen as constituting separate notionality.

Comment: The Word grammar editor is totally useless; turn it off. As for the phenomenon, _be the same (`X`) (as)_ is a [reciprocal predicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/152096/15299), and that means it takes a singular verb with a singular subject and a plural verb with a conjoined subject: *`A` **is** the same (`X`) as `B`; `B` **is** the same (`X`) as `A`;* but *`A` and `B` **are** the same (`X`).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental rule (in US English, at least) is: if you have two subjects connected with "and", then you must take a plural verb.    By comparison, if you have two subjects connected with "or," then the verb takes the singular/plural to match the second subject.  "The Smiths or Mike is going to do the job."  and "Mike or the Smiths are going to do the job."

As the comments suggested, regardless of how many actual items the subject nouns refer to, the fact that you have multiple subjects means the verb form must be plural.

PS trusting MS Word on grammar or spelling is even dumber than trusting MS Excel on math.

Answer (score 1):

The verb changes only due to the subject: in this case **two** dogs, therefore a **plural** verb. This is irrespective of the fact that the object is singular.

> Rocky **and** Coco are the same dog
>
> Rocky **is** the same dog as Coco and Rufus

And although Word's grammar check can be useful, don't take is as gospel.