# Should I use singular or plural after a series of two gerunds? "Killing their children and destroying their homes is/are"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, gerunds

- Killing their children and destroying their homes **is** not enough - they must humiliate them too.
- Killing their children and destroying their homes **are** not enough - they must humiliate them too.

Comment: The first sounds correct. Does [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/153636/244156) help?

Comment: Gerund phrases can be subjects. Two subjects make it plural.

Comment: I you prefer killing and destroying as a unit, you'd use singular. If you prefer them as separate activities, plural.