# 'Relates to' vs. 'Is Related to'

Tags: grammar, verbs, word-usage, participles

Does the choice between passive/active voice make any difference in the examples below?

1. *My question **relates to** your earlier work.*
2. *My question **is related to** you earlier work.*
3. *Nerve cells **relate to** one another through thin fibers.*
4. *Nerve cells **are related to** one another through thin fibers.*

Comment: Not much difference, IMHO

Comment: _(Be) related to_ is a kinship term, a [reciprocal predicate adjective](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/152096/15299) -- _She's related to him/He's related to her/He and she are related_. It's formed from the past participle of _relate_, a verb that ultimately involves telling a story (_So I'll relate the family's fate since Dad got put in jail_ - 'Wallaby Stew'). I'm not sure which one is primary here -- stories are mostly about relatives, one way or another -- but the term has come to be metaphorially extended to any kind of connection, especially at a distance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb *relate* denotes several types of **connection** between multiple entities:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT] 1.0 Make or show a connection between:
>   *the study examines social change within the city and relates it to developments
>   in the country as a whole
>
>   a supercomputer could relate all those factors*
>
> 1.1 (be related) Be causally connected:
>   *high unemployment is related to high crime rates*
>
> 1.2 (be related) Be connected by blood or marriage:
>   *he was related to my mother
>
>   people who are distantly related*
>
> 1.3 [NO OBJECT] (relate to) Have reference to; concern:
>   *the new legislation related to corporate activities*
>
> 2.0 [NO OBJECT] (relate to) Feel sympathy for or identify with:
>   *kids related to him because he was so rebellious*
>
> 3.0 Give an account of; narrate:
>   *various versions of the story have been related by the locals*
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

---

The history of *relate* and its constituent parts offers some insight into the nature of the relationship *relate* describes:

> *[relate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=relate&allowed_in_frame=0)* (v.)
>   1520s, "to recount, tell,"
>   from Middle French *relater* "refer, report" (14c.)
>   and directly from Latin *relatus*, used as past participle of *referre* "bring back, bear back" (see refer),
>   from *re-* "back, again" + ***latus*** (see oblate (n.)).
>
> Meaning "stand in some relation; have reference or respect" is from 1640s;
>   transitive sense of "bring (something) into relation with (something else)" is from 1690s.
>   Meaning "to establish a relation between" is from 1771.
>   Sense of "to feel connected or sympathetic to" is attested from 1950, originally in psychology jargon.
>
> *[re-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=re-&allowed_in_frame=0)*
>   word-forming element meaning "**back to the original place**; again, anew, once more," also with a sense of "undoing," c. 1200,
>   from Old French and directly from Latin *re-* "again, back, anew, against,"
>   "Latin combining form conceivably from Indo-European *wret-, metathetical variant of *wert- "to turn" [Watkins].
>
> *[oblate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=oblate&allowed_in_frame=0)* (n.)
>   "person devoted to religious work," 1756,
>   from Medieval Latin *oblatus*, noun use of Latin oblatus, variant past participle of offerre "to offer, to bring before,"
>   from *ob-* (see ob-) + ***latus*** "**carried, borne**" (used as suppletive past participle of ferre "to bear"),
>   from *tlatos, from PIE root *tele- "**to bear, carry**" (see extol).
>   <sub>*etymonline.com **emphasis** added*</sub>

It doesn't always happen this way, because meanings change arbitrarily over time, but all of the ODO definitions continue the **carry back to the original** theme established by the origin of *relate*. Consider the intuitive interpretation of the ODO example sentences:

> - *the study examines social change within the city and **carries it back to the original** developments in the country as a whole*
> - 1.1 *high crime rates are **carried back to [the original** cause] high unemployment*
> - 1.2 *people who are distantly **carried back to [the original** ancestor]*
> - 1.3 *the new legislation **carried back to [the original** issue]corporate activities*
> - 2.0 *kids were **carried back to [the original** rebel] him because he was so rebellious*
> - 3.0  *the locals **have carried back** various versions of **the [original]** story*

---

Examples sentences 1 and 2 of the OP *relate* precisely to the **carry back** theme of ODO definition 1.3. *Relate* connects the noun phrase *my question* conceptually to the noun phrase *your earlier work*, revealing that the question **carries back to the original** earlier work.

---

Example sentences 3 and 4 of the OP seems to *relate* weakly to ODO definition 1.1. The noun phrase *nerve cells* is connected to the noun phrase *one another*. Since neither actually **carries back to** the other as **the original**, it sounds slightly off to the native ear.

Example sentences 3 and 4 could be a weak metaphoric application of ODO definition 2.0, since the nerve cells could be seen as "related in the same fashion as people are related*, but then the preposition *by* would need to replace *with* to maintain the *people blood* analogy between nerve cells and fibers.

Example sentences 3 and 4 could also be a weak metaphoric application of ODO definition 3.0, since the nerve cells could be seen as relating by means of fibers in the same fashion as people relate with stories. This metaphor is weak because the *people story* analogy would be fulfilled more precisely with *nerve cell impulse*.

Examples 3 and 4 are **not wrong** necessarily, but they do stretch the meaning of relate beyond its established core.

---

Although the present form and the participial form are almost universally interchangeable in meaning, the present form establishes a subtle emphasis on the **activity** of *carrying back*. In contrast, the participial form establishes a subtle emphasis on the **status**. The participle form is not a passive construction *per se*, but the focus on the status gives the reader a **static adjectival** sense of the meaning, because of its similarity with a predicate adjective construction:

1. Activity focus: My question **relates** to your earlier work.
2. Status focus: My question **is** related to you earlier work.
3. Activity focus: Nerve cells **relate** to one another through thin fibers.
4. Status focus: Nerve cells **are** related to one another through thin fibers.

**Conclusion**

The difference between the present form *relate[s]* and the participial form *is/are related* creates a subtle difference in focus, that will have a slight influence on the interpretation of the sentences. Spot on usage of *relate*:

> 1. **My question** connects to your earlier work.
>
> vs.
>
> 2. **[I am]** connecting my question to your original earlier work.

Slightly stretched usage of *relate*:

> 3. **Nerve cells** connect to one another through thin fibers.
>
> vs.
>
> 4. **Thin fibers** are connecting nerve cells to one another.

Answer (score 3):

> My question relates to your earlier work.

This usually means that I am asking (you) about your earlier work.

> My question is related to your earlier work.

This usually means that I have formulated a question that addresses a similar subject to the one you addressed in your work. I'm letting you know about it in case you have any thoughts on it or believe it's worth investigating.

**Note** My above replies could be modified if the context was different. You haven't given any context so I had to go on nuance alone.

> Nerve cells relate to one another through thin fibers.

I don't think they do. I think that they **connect to** or **communicate with** each other via axons and dendrites. Maybe it would be worth rewriting those last two examples and submitting them as a separate question. The answer would be different from the one I have provided above.