# Changing the order of "that" clause

Tags: that

I saw the following sentence in a book:

> That people were so willing to respond is one measure of the
>   importance of the topic.

Is there any reason to bring the "that" clause to the beginning of the sentence? Does it differ in meaning from the normal sentence?

Comment: Have a look at the section titled [Why do we use inversion and fronting?](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/exploring-inversion-and-fronting.html) Taken in isolation I can't see any particular nuance imparted by your cited example, but if you consider it in the full context, I suppose it's possible your fronted clause is being used *as a cohesive device to link a clause or sentence to what has just gone before* (one of 3 specific possibilities covered there). But most likely it's just a "meaningless" random stylistic choice.

Comment: Fronting it stresses the importance of the topic. Starting 'One measure' stresses the analytical methodology (ie that there are various measures).

Comment: So that we can understand your question properly, can you please add what you consider to be the 'normal' sentence?

Comment: @FumbleFingers That sentence is located at the beginning of the paragraph. So, I don't think it is relevant to its previous text (as there is nothing before this). Thank you for the link you provided.

Comment: Actually, that is the 'basic' order. _It is one measure of the importance of the topic that people were so willing to respond_ is the extraposed counterpart, which many people would prefer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers See what BillJ said. There's no fronting of anything here. There's just a finite clause functioning as Subject.

Comment: One point of interest is that in the extraposed version, the subordinate clause is not part of the predicative complement. The PC is just _one measure of the importance of the topic_ just as it is in the non-extraposed version.

Comment: It sure beats the unnecessarily wordy, "Due to the fact that," as in "Due to the fact that people were so willing to respond is one measure of the importance of the topic." Economy of expression is sometimes a good thing. Don

Comment: @Araucaria Man: I'm not too hot on precise definitions, as you probably know. But BillJ's rephrasing also looks like "fronting" to me, given that the *standard* word order in English is Subject: **One measure of the importance of the topic** Verb: **is** Object: **that people were so willing to respond**. That's the "natural" version, and any deviation is a stylistic choice, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

> *[That people were so willing to respond] **is** [one measure of the importance of the topic].*

This is an equative sentence, identifying one noun phrase with another, joined by *is*.  One of the noun phrases is a subordinate clause, a *that*-complement. Such clauses occurring as subject noun phrases (as here), are subject to [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299) with many verbs, including *be*.

- *It  **is** [one measure of the importance of the topic] [that people were so willing to respond].*

However, equative sentences can be reversed, since this is an equivalence relation.

- *[One measure of the importance of the topic] **is** [that people were so willing to respond].*

This isn't a movement of the clause so much as a swapping of the noun phrases,  similar to what happens with [reciprocal verbs like *marry*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/152096/15299). There's no difference between the two sentences, except that Extraposition is ungrammatical without a clause as subject:

- **It **is** [that people were so willing to respond] [one measure of the importance of the topic]*.

Comment: So you say the sentence in the book is ungrammatical?

Comment: No. The sentence that I said is ungrammatical is not the sentence in the book.